# accessing cpu information from linux kernel module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cpu-usage

i need to access the cpu idle time for every one minute from a linux kernel module and print it to kern.log so that i can plot a graph for statistics.
Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write a kernel module for that, that information is already provided in `/proc/stat`:

```
$ awk ' /^cpu/ { print $1, $5 / 100; } ' /proc/stat
cpu 251908
cpu0 63149.6  <--- Total IDLE time in seconds 
cpu1 62053.2
...
```

Where 100 is `USER_HZ` constant (100 on most systems).

If you still wish to write kernel module, than you can re-use `/proc/stat` code from here: [fs/proc/stat.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/proc/stat.c#L80).